# How to sort multiple ArrayLists based off order of another?

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to go out about sorting multiple lists based off of the sorted order of one list. Currently the lists are in order based off their indices. The departureTime list holds strings of time in the format (00:00 AM/PM). They are initialized like this:

```
public static List<String> departureTime = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> mode = new ArrayList<String>(); 
public static List<String> busNo = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> busStopName = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> arrivalTime = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> dur = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I need to sort all lists based of the sorted order of departure times in the departureTime ArrayList. What's the best way to go about sorting these lists without changing the resulting data structure. Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: It would be easier to tackle this problem by creating an object that has the values from each of your lists. You can then have one list of objects and sort on the value you care about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comment, it would have been easier to create an object containing all the values, and then just sort the object list.

If this is for some reason impossible, you will need to code your own sort method, for instance selection sort, while making the permutations operations on all objects in the lists.

Here is a simple but non optimal algorithm. Feel free to adapt it for some other sort. This would work only if all lists have the same length.

```
    public void sort() {
    String[] departureTimeArray = departureTime.toArray(new String[departureTime.size()]);
    String[] modeArray = mode.toArray(new String[mode.size()]);
    //here you convert the other lists to arrays

    int lenD = departureTimeArray.length;
    int j = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<lenD;i++){
        j = i;
        for(int k = i;k<lenD;k++){
            if(departureTimeArray[j].compareTo(departureTimeArray[k])>0){
                j = k;
            }
        }
        permutation(departureTimeArray, i, j);
        permutation(modeArray, i, j);
        //here do the same for other arrays
    }

    departureTime = Arrays.asList(departureTimeArray);
    mode = Arrays.asList(modeArray);
    //here convert back arrays to list
}

private void permutation(String[] array, int i, int j) {
    String tmp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = tmp;
}
```

See for instance here for the selection sort algorithm :
[selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)

Comment: Hello Yves, I have implemented your solution, but my application is crashing as a result. All of my lists are of the same length and the format of each string in departureTimeArray is hh:mm a (3:32pm). Logcat states there is a problem with the casting: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]. However, departureTimeArray is initialized as a ArrayList of type String. Do you know why this might be happening? Thanks, Matt

Comment: I had to alter your answer a bit to deal with the casting error. I was able to get it working. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I have just seen your answer, I guess I had to give a new String[] as an argument in the toArray method, I modified my answer in that way

Answer (score 1):

You could save the index of each departure time before sorting in a `Hashmap<String, Integer>`. Then sort only that list as usual, then save again the indexes in another hashmap.

Now you know that a given string was in position `n` before sorting and is now in position `n'` after sorting. So you can manually swap the other lists's elements with this info.

This approach is brittle, because if there were repeated elements in the list, then you can't know which one was which after sorting. So you are better off creating a container class as suggested in the other answers.