# How to sort a custom adapter with int and string

Tags: android, sorting, listview

I have a list view and I want to sort the list view with four categories, String name (alphabetical), String Category (alphabetical), String Date (from new to old), int Price (from 99999 to 0). I want to sort the list view when radio button is clicked.

This is my Expenses Activity when I want the list view

```
public class ExpensesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnAddExpenses;
ListView lvExpenses;
CustomArrayAdapterExpenses adapter;
ArrayList<String> alExpensesName;
ArrayList<String> alExpensesPrice;
ArrayList<String> alExpensesCategory;
ArrayList<String> alExpensesDate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_expenses);

    final GlobalClass globalClass = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
    final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    btnAddExpenses = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddExpenses);
    lvExpenses = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExpenses);

    alExpensesName = globalClass.allTrips.get(extras.getInt("position")).getItemsString();
    alExpensesPrice = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Double i: globalClass.allTrips.get(extras.getInt("position")).getItemsCost()){
        alExpensesPrice.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }
    alExpensesCategory = globalClass.allTrips.get(extras.getInt("position")).getItemsCategory();
    alExpensesDate = globalClass.allTrips.get(extras.getInt("position")).getItemsDate();
    adapter = new CustomArrayAdapterExpenses(this, alExpensesName, alExpensesCategory , alExpensesPrice, alExpensesDate);
    lvExpenses.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnAddExpenses.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ExpensesActivity.this, AddExpensesActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", extras.getInt("position"));
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    lvExpenses.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ExpensesActivity.this, ExpenseActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", extras.getInt("position"));
            intent.putExtra("positionExpense", position);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.rbName:
            if (checked) {
                /*
                Collections.sort(alExpensesName, new Comparator<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(String text1, String text2)
                    {
                        return text1.compareToIgnoreCase(text2);
                    }
                });
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                */
            }

                break;
        case R.id.rbPrice:
            if (checked){

            }
                break;
        case R.id.rbCategory:
            if (checked) {

            }
            break;
        case R.id.rbDate:
            if (checked) {

            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();
    final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    Intent intent = new Intent(ExpensesActivity.this, TripActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("position", extras.getInt("position"));
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

This is CustomArrayAdapterExpenses

```
public class CustomArrayAdapterExpenses extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<String> alExpensesName;
ArrayList<String> alExpensesPrice;
ArrayList<String> alExpensesCategory;
ArrayList<String> alExpensesDate;

Context mContext;

//constructor
public CustomArrayAdapterExpenses(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> alExpensesName, ArrayList<String> alExpensesCategory, ArrayList<String> alExpensesPrice, ArrayList<String> alExpensesDate) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.alExpensesName = alExpensesName;
    this.alExpensesCategory = alExpensesCategory;
    this.alExpensesPrice = alExpensesPrice;
    this.alExpensesDate = alExpensesDate;
}

public int getCount() {
    return alExpensesName.size();
}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_expenses, viewGroup, false);

    TextView tvExpensesName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvExpensesName);
    TextView tvExpensesCategory = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvExpensesCategory);
    TextView tvExpensesPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvExpensesPrice);
    TextView tvExpensesDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvExpensesDate);


    tvExpensesName.setText(alExpensesName.get(position));
    tvExpensesCategory.setText(alExpensesCategory.get(position));
    tvExpensesPrice.setText(alExpensesPrice.get(position));
    tvExpensesDate.setText(alExpensesDate.get(position));


    return row;
}
}
```

This is my Trip Class

```
public class Trip {

/** A map with category as key and the associed list of items as value */
Map<String,List<Item>> expanses;

private String name;
private Calendar FirstDate;
private Calendar EndDate;
private int HowMuchDays;
private String SFirstDate, SEndDate;
public ArrayList<String> ExpensesCategory = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<String> Adults = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<String> Children = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<String> ShoppingName = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<Double> ShoppingPrice = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<String> ShoppingCategory = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<TraveledDay> TraveledDays = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<Fuel> Fuels = new ArrayList<>();
public double budget = 0;

/** An item in the expanses list */
static class Item {
    final String name;
    final double cost;
    final String Category;
    final String Date;
    String Description;
    public Item(String name, double cost, String Category, String Date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.Category = Category;
        this.Date = Date;
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return this.name + " (" + this.cost + "$)";
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getCategory(){
        return Category;
    }
    public double getCost(){
        return cost;
    }
    public String getDate(){
        return Date;
    }
    public String getDescription(){ return Description; }
}

static class TraveledDay {
    final String Date;
    final int FirstKM;
    final int EndKM;
    final int KM;
    public TraveledDay(int FirstKM, int EndKM, String Date) {
        this.FirstKM = FirstKM;
        this.EndKM = EndKM;
        this.Date = Date;
        KM = EndKM - FirstKM;
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return this.Date + " (" + this.KM + ")";
    }
    public int getFirstKM(){
        return FirstKM;
    }
    public int getEndKM(){
        return EndKM;
    }
    public int getKM(){
        return KM;
    }
    public String getDate(){
        return Date;
    }
}

static class Fuel {
    final String Date;
    final int CurrentKM;
    final int LastKM;
    final int SumKM;
    final double SumLiter;
    final double LiterPrice;
    final double SumPrice;

    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }

    public int getCurrentKM() {
        return CurrentKM;
    }

    public int getLastKM() {
        return LastKM;
    }

    public int getSumKM() {
        return SumKM;
    }

    public double getSumLiter() {
        return SumLiter;
    }

    public double getLiterPrice() {
        return LiterPrice;
    }

    public double getSumPrice() {
        return SumPrice;
    }

    public Fuel(String Date, int CurrentKM, int LastKM, int SumKM, double SumLiter, double LiterPrice, double SumPrice) {
        this.Date = Date;
        this.CurrentKM = CurrentKM;
        this.LastKM = LastKM;
        this.SumKM = SumKM;
        this.SumLiter = SumLiter;
        this.LiterPrice = LiterPrice;
        this.SumPrice = SumPrice;
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return this.Date + " (" + this.SumKM + ")";
    }
}

public Trip(String name, Calendar FirstDate, Calendar EndDate, String SFirstDate, String SEndDate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.FirstDate = FirstDate;
    this.EndDate = EndDate;
    HowMuchDays = (int)((EndDate.getTime().getTime() - FirstDate.getTime().getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    this.SEndDate = SEndDate;
    this.SFirstDate = SFirstDate;
    this.expanses = new HashMap<String,List<Item>>();
    ExpensesCategory.add("כרטיסי טיסה");
    ExpensesCategory.add("לינה");
    ExpensesCategory.add("תחבורה");
    ExpensesCategory.add("אוכל");
    ExpensesCategory.add("אתרים");
    ExpensesCategory.add("שונות");
    for (String cat: ExpensesCategory) { // init the categories with empty lists
        this.expanses.put(cat, new ArrayList<Item>());
    }
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public Calendar getFirstDate(){
    return FirstDate;
}
public Calendar getEndDate(){
    return EndDate;
}
public Integer getHowMuchDays(){
    return HowMuchDays;
}
public String getSFirstDate(){
    return SFirstDate;
}
public String getSEndDate(){
    return SEndDate;
}


/** Register a new expanse to the trip. */
public void add(String item, double cost, String category, String Date) {
    List<Item> list = this.expanses.get(category);
    if (list == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Category '"+category+"' does not exist.");
    list.add( new Item(item, cost, category, Date) );
}

public void addTraveledDay(int FirstKM, int EndKM, String Date) {
    ArrayList<TraveledDay> list = TraveledDays;
    list.add( new TraveledDay(FirstKM, EndKM, Date) );
}

public void removeTraveledDay(int index) {
    ArrayList<TraveledDay> list = TraveledDays;
    list.remove(index);
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getTraveledFirstKM(){
    ArrayList<Integer> listInteger = new ArrayList<>();
    for (TraveledDay traveledDay : TraveledDays){
        listInteger.add(traveledDay.getFirstKM());
    }
    return listInteger;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getTraveledEndKM(){
    ArrayList<Integer> listInteger = new ArrayList<>();
    for (TraveledDay traveledDay : TraveledDays){
        listInteger.add(traveledDay.getEndKM());
    }
    return listInteger;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getTraveledKM(){
    ArrayList<Integer> listInteger = new ArrayList<>();
    for (TraveledDay traveledDay : TraveledDays){
        listInteger.add(traveledDay.getKM());
    }
    return listInteger;
}

public ArrayList<String> getTraveledDate() {
    ArrayList<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (TraveledDay traveledDay : TraveledDays){
        listString.add(traveledDay.getDate());
    }
    return listString;
}

public ArrayList<String> getFuelDate() {
    ArrayList<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Fuel fuel : Fuels){
        listString.add(fuel.getDate());
    }
    return listString;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getFuelCurrentKM(){
    ArrayList<Integer> listInteger = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Fuel fuel : Fuels){
        listInteger.add(fuel.getCurrentKM());
    }
    return listInteger;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getFuelLastKM(){
    ArrayList<Integer> listInteger = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Fuel fuel : Fuels){
        listInteger.add(fuel.getLastKM());
    }
    return listInteger;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getFuelSumKM(){
    ArrayList<Integer> listInteger = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Fuel fuel : Fuels){
        listInteger.add(fuel.getSumKM());
    }
    return listInteger;
}

public ArrayList<Double> getFuelSumLiter(){
    ArrayList<Double> listDouble = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Fuel fuel : Fuels){
        listDouble.add(fuel.getSumLiter());
    }
    return listDouble;
}

public ArrayList<Double> getFuelLiterPrice(){
    ArrayList<Double> listDouble = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Fuel fuel : Fuels){
        listDouble.add(fuel.getLiterPrice());
    }
    return listDouble;
}

public ArrayList<Double> getFuelSumPrice(){
    ArrayList<Double> listDouble = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Fuel fuel : Fuels){
        listDouble.add(fuel.getSumPrice());
    }
    return listDouble;
}

/** Get the expanses, given a category.
 * @return  a fresh ArrayList containing the category elements, or null if the category does not exists
 */
public List<Item> getItems(String category) {
    List<Item> list = this.expanses.get(category);
    if (list == null)
        return null;
    return new ArrayList<Item>(list);
}

/** Get the expanses, given a category.
 * @return  a fresh ArrayList containing all the elements
 */
public List<Item> getItems() {
    List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
    for (List<Item> l: this.expanses.values()) // fill with each category items
        list.addAll(l);
    return list;
}

public ArrayList<String> getItemsString() {
    List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
    for (List<Item> l: this.expanses.values()) // fill with each category items
        list.addAll(l);
    ArrayList<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Item item : list){
        listString.add(item.getName());
    }
    return listString;
}

public ArrayList<String> getItemsDescription() {
    List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
    for (List<Item> l: this.expanses.values()) // fill with each category items
        list.addAll(l);
    ArrayList<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Item item : list){
        listString.add(item.getDescription());
    }
    return listString;
}

public ArrayList<String> getItemsDate() {
    List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
    for (List<Item> l: this.expanses.values()) // fill with each category items
        list.addAll(l);
    ArrayList<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Item item : list){
        listString.add(item.getDate());
    }
    return listString;
}

public ArrayList<Double> getItemsCost(){
    List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
    for (List<Item> l: this.expanses.values()) // fill with each category items
        list.addAll(l);
    ArrayList<Double> listDouble = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Item item : list){
        listDouble.add(item.getCost());
    }
    return listDouble;
}

public ArrayList<String> getItemsCategory() {
    List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
    for (List<Item> l: this.expanses.values()) // fill with each category items
        list.addAll(l);
    ArrayList<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Item item : list){
        listString.add(item.getCategory());
    }
    return listString;
}

/** Get the total cost, given a category. */
public double getCost(String category) {
    List<Item> list = this.expanses.get(category);
    if (list == null)
        return -1;
    double cost = 0;
    for (Item item: list)
        cost += item.cost;
    return cost;
}

/** Get the total cost. */
public double getCost() {
    double cost = 0;
    for (List<Item> l: this.expanses.values())
        for (Item item: l)
            cost += item.cost;
    cost *= 1000;
    cost = (int)(cost);
    cost /= 1000;
    return cost;
}
}
```

This is my global class

```
public class GlobalClass extends Application {

ArrayList<Trip> allTrips = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<String> allTripsString() {
    ArrayList<String> allTripsString = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Trip trip : allTrips){
        allTripsString.add(trip.getName());
    }
    return allTripsString;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> allTripsHowMuchDate() {
    ArrayList<Integer> allTripsString = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Trip trip : allTrips){
        allTripsString.add(trip.getHowMuchDays());
    }
    return allTripsString;
}

public ArrayList<String> allTripsSFirstDate() {
    ArrayList<String> allTripsString = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Trip trip : allTrips){
        allTripsString.add(trip.getSFirstDate());
    }
    return allTripsString;
}

public ArrayList<String> allTripsSEndDate() {
    ArrayList<String> allTripsString = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Trip trip : allTrips){
        allTripsString.add(trip.getSEndDate());
    }
    return allTripsString;
}


public void saveList(Context context, List<Trip> list) {

    String PREFS_NAME = "PRODUCT_APP";
    String KEY_NAME = "KEY_NAME";

    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonlist = gson.toJson(list);

    editor.putString(KEY_NAME, jsonlist);

    editor.commit();
}
public void loadList(Context context){
    String PREFS_NAME = "PRODUCT_APP";
    String KEY_NAME = "KEY_NAME";

    SharedPreferences settings;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonlist = settings.getString(KEY_NAME, "");

    if (jsonlist.isEmpty()) {
        allTrips = new ArrayList<>();
    } else {
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Trip>>(){}.getType();
        allTrips = gson.fromJson(jsonlist, type);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Pass the single list of Item objects to your adapter and get the all four attributes from Item. On RadioButtonClick sort the list of Items based on sorted type. and update the adapter This way your code will be cleaner and meet your requirement.

Comment: I just want to sort the adapter, In the first code I have a 4 list views so I want to sort them.

Comment: Can you help me please?

Comment: What do you mean by 4 list view? Based on your code its looking like you have one list view and 4 separate array list for each attribute which you are passing to adapter.

Comment: yes, I have 4 array list and one list view, when I sort the list not 
organized. for example if I have two rows.
name: banana, category: food, price: 5, date: today
name: apple, category: food, price: 10, date: today
so after I clicked the button it looks like this:
name: apple, category: food, price: 5, date: today
name: banana, category: food, price: 10, date: today
so how I fix that?

Comment: As there are 4 different array list and you are sorting one array list at a time. Because of this mapping between list element lost. To fix the problem find below the solution.

Comment: but how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solution of the issue:
1. Easy way to solve is to create a custom class having 4 attributes: name, category, price and expanse date or use existing class Item. Pass the array of custom objects to adapter. If you try to sort this custom objects array based on any key mapping between different attributes will be never lost and it meets your problem. On RadioButtonClick listener sort the custom array and update the adapter and notify.

2. Try to sort the 4 array simultaneously based on one key. Like if you want to sort based on name, try to implement the selection sort on name array and on swapping swap elements in all four array to maintain the mapping between all four. Performance of sorting is not good in this solution. To implement this refer [How to sort multiple ArrayLists based off order of another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992440/how-to-sort-multiple-arraylists-based-off-order-of-another)

Comment: can you explain more the way with the custom class? I have custom class so what I need to add to the custom class if I want this will work?

Comment: how can I do this?

Comment: Try to write your code in the way as I suggested and if you face any issue I will fix. I don't want to write complete code for you. Or tell me specifically where are facing issue in understanding as I already mentioned what you have to do.