# Sort Array in Recyclerview (Java, Android)

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

```
   package com.example.sander.app;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Sander on 6-4-2017.
 */

public class RecycleFrame extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> cPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> code = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> latitude = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> longitude = new ArrayList<>();
    GPSTracker gps;
    ArrayList<Double> dLatitude = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Double> dLongitude = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Float> distance = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    public RecycleFrame() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_view, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Integer id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.action_A_Z){
            //Sorts the garages from A to Z
            Collections.sort(names);
            //Refreshes the fragment
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
            return true;
        }
        else if(id == R.id.action_Z_A){
            //Sorts the garages from Z to A
            Collections.reverse(names);
            //Refreshes the fragment
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.short_distance){
            Collections.sort(distance);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycle, container, false);
        final RecyclerView VRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
        RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        String url= "http://test.dontstealmywag.ga/api/parkgarage_all.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Do something with the response
                        try{
                            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray values=o.getJSONArray("");
                            if(names.size() == 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject jsonObject = values.getJSONObject(i);
                                    dataList.add(new Data(jsonObject.getString("parkgarage_name"), jsonObject.getString("charging_capcatity"), jsonObject.getDouble("langitude"),
                                            jsonObject.getDouble("longitude"), jsonObject.getString("parkgarage_code"), distance.get(i)));
                                    //names.add(jsonObject.getString("parkgarage_name"));
                                    //cPoints.add(jsonObject.getString("charging_capacity"));
                                    //code.add(jsonObject.getString("parkgarage_code"));
                                    //latitude.add(jsonObject.getString("langitude"));
                                    //longitude.add(jsonObject.getString("longitude"));
                                    dLatitude.add(jsonObject.getDouble("langitude"));
                                    dLongitude.add(jsonObject.getDouble("longitude"));
                                }
                            }
                        }  catch (JSONException ex){}
                        gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
                        //check if gps is on
                        if(!gps.canGetLocation()){
                            gps.showSettingsAlert();
                        }
                        Location myLocation = new Location("");
                        myLocation.setLatitude(gps.getLatitude());
                        myLocation.setLongitude(gps.getLongitude());
                        for(int z = 0; z < latitude.size(); z++){
                            Location parkingGarage = new Location("");
                            parkingGarage.setLatitude(dLatitude.get(z));
                            parkingGarage.setLongitude(dLongitude.get(z));
                            distance.add(myLocation.distanceTo(parkingGarage)/1000);
                        }


                        VRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                        //RecycleAdapter adapter = new RecycleAdapter(names, cPoints, code, latitude, longitude, distance);
                        RecycleAdapter adapter = new RecycleAdapter(dataList);
                        VRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                        VRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Handle error
                    }
                });
        rq.add(stringRequest);
        return view;
    }
}
```

This is my RecycleFrame code, below is my RecyclerAdapter code

```
    package com.example.sander.app;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Sander on 6-4-2017.
 */

public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Data> ArrayListData;
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public CardView mCardView;
        public TextView TextViewNames;

        public MyViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            mCardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            TextViewNames = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_names);

        }

    }
    public RecycleAdapter(ArrayList<Data> names){
        ArrayListData = names;
        //ArrayCharging= cPoints;
        //ArrayCode = code;
        //ArrayLatitude = latitude;
        //ArrayLongitude = longitude;
        //ArrayDistance = distance;
    }
    @Override
    public RecycleAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_view, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position){

        holder.TextViewNames.setText(String.valueOf(ArrayListData.get(position)));
        //holder.TextViewNames.setText("Naam: " + ArrayNames.get(position));
        //holder.TextViewCharging.setText("Oplaadpunten: " + ArrayCharging.get(position));
        //holder.TextViewCode.setText("Code: " + ArrayCode.get(position));
        //holder.TextViewLatitude.setText("Positie: (" + ArrayLatitude.get(position) + ", " + ArrayLongitude.get(position)+ ")");
        //holder.TextViewDistance.setText(String.valueOf(ArrayDistance.get(position)));
        //holder.mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_local_parking_black_24dp);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return ArrayListData.size(); }
}
```

What I want is the following: I want to be able to press a item in a 3 dot menu and sort it from A to Z, Z to A & sort in on distance to the certain location. Sorting works correct (except for the distance but I can fix that myself). The only problem is that when I sort from A to Z or Z to A or distance the code & name & cPoints are not matching anymore. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per you code you have multiple arraylist for name, distance, cpoint and when you sort one list the mapping between sorted list and all others list lost.
To fix this you have to keep the mapping between all whenever you sort based on attribute.

Better create a custom class with fields like name, distance, cpoint.... and whenever you sort on one attribute sort the list of custom objects. By this way mapping between multiple list is not lost.

There is another inefficient approach to solve the problem. But I will not recommend.
Try to sort the 4 array simultaneously based on one key. Like if you want to sort based on name, try to implement the selection sort on name array and on swapping swap elements in all four array to maintain the mapping between all four. Performance of sorting is not good in this solution. To implement this refer [How to sort multiple ArrayLists based off order of another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992440/how-to-sort-multiple-arraylists-based-off-order-of-another)

Comment: Any example on how to do this

Comment: I can give you example but then its like copy paste. Better try with above suggestion and if you face any issue you are welcome.

Comment: public class Data {
    public String names;
    public String cPoints;
    public String latitude;
    public String longitude;
    public String code;
    public Float distance;
    public Data(String n, String cP, String lat, String lon, String c, Float dis ){
        names = n;
        cPoints = cP;
        latitude = lat;
        longitude = lon; 
        code = c;
        distance = dis;
    }
} So far I made this, but how can I add data to it from my JSON file in the RecycleFrame code ?

Comment: In for loop where you are iterating json array, create the object of Data and pass the list to adapter and notify.     JSONObject jsonObject = values.getJSONObject(i);
                    dataList.add(new Data(jsonObject.getString("parkgarage_name"), jsonObject.getString("charging_capacity")), jsonObject.getString("langitude"), jsonObject.getDouble("longitude"), jsonObject.getString("parkgarage_code"), ..);

Comment: dataList should be something like Data [] = {}, Am I right? Because if I do this it doesn't know the "add" method. Nevermind it should be ArrayList<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Yes dataList is arraylist not array. Its best practice to use interface in declaration.   List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Yeah I've fixed my "issue". Now I can sort things the way I want. Thanks!

Comment: @Sanderbakker Accept the answer if same solution is working for you.